# Entity Framework REST Services in Azure - Get Entity Remotely

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I have some entity framework REST services in c# that get data from a SQL server. These services will be hosted on Azure.

The db can't be opened for remote connections, I don't want every query going through the service bus relay, and I can't host the DB in Azure.

Is there a way to only have the connection to the DB go through the service bus so that entity is then loaded into memory on Azure then the queries can go against that?

I'm trying something along the lines of:

```
public class ATPublicRestContext : DbContext
{
    public ATPublicRestContext() : base("name=WEBEntities")
    {
        //do something here to call the dbcontext through a service bus? 
        //Is that even possible

        //or somehow get base("name-WEBEntities") to call the service bus 
        //binding instead of the connection string to the DB?
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the REST service can't be hosted on premises? Not arguing your stance on Azure, but sounds like your options a severely limited on what you can do here.

Comment: The website that uses the services will also be hosted in Azure, and there can be no access points opened up to allow calls from the site to REST services within the firewall, we don't want every call going through the service bus

Comment: Set the REST service in a DMZ that is segregated from the database network, then only open the ports needed for the REST service to communicate to the database (a fairly standard practice). In the end, if the rule is "No inbound data calls from external sources" then you are going to have a really hard time getting this to work from Azure.

Comment: I believe the right 'pattern' to user for this would be a relay service - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-what-is-it

Comment: Ya I'm familiar with using a relay, but we don't want every query going through the relay, so I'm trying to figure out how to ONLY have the DB connection go through the relay then have the entity stored in memory to query against

Comment: We use Azure Relay today in our development environment... the performance hit is considerable when compared to the on prem instances of our APIs that we have. We are moving to [Express Routes](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/expressroute/), but is coming at a cost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to post another answer since you seem dead set on not allowing all queries across the hybrid connection.  However, the feasibility of this really depends on the amount of data and how often it changes.

You could easily cache entities into memory at start-up.  So, when your application starts, it would hit the db and populate these collections.  Then, your actual api controllers would query these collections, not the database. 
 This is a pretty standard approach for small, mostly static data, but certainly not large amounts of data that changes often.

Potential Issues:

1. Can you reasonably put all of this data into memory?
2. Will you ever need to scale-out the api?  If so, now you need multiple copies of the data in memory, in multiple places.
3. How often does the data change?  If there is any change, you'll need to invalidate the in-memory data and reload from the database.

Another way to slice it would be to not load it on startup, but keep track of which entities have been loaded so the first request can trigger the load.

However, much like I said in my first answer, I would really try to prove that the hybrid connection is a problem before doing anything like this.  But, this is a way to accomplish what you seem to want to do.

**UPDATE**:

Based on your comment, here is the general idea:  Somewhere in your startup code, you would call a method to populate your entity collections.  These could just be generic lists contained in a class, something like this:

```
// in your startup code
EntityRepository.SaturateEntities();

...

// here is the entity repo
public class EntityRepository
{
    public static List<SomeEntity> SomeEntities { get; private set; }
    public static List<SomeOtherEntity> SomeOtherEntities { get; private set; }

    public static void SaturateEntities()
    {
        // _db is assumed to be your entity framework context
        // ToList() will actually execute the query and return the results
        SomeEntities = _db.SomeEntities.ToList();
        SomeOtherEntities = _db.SomeOtherEntities.ToList();
    }
}
```

Now, in your API controllers, you would query the lists in the EntityRepository instead of querying the data context.  There are lots of different ways you could do this, but hopefully this gives you the general idea.  Also, instead of loading all on startup, you could wait until the first request.  So, the repo would just keep track of which lists where already initialized and only load them up once they are needed.

Comment: 1. Yes, it's only about 80 000 records
2. No I don't think we will need to scale it out
3. Not often, maybe twice a year the records would be refreshed. Never updated by the REST APIs

This does sound like something that could work and meets my requirements. Any idea how I go about that? An example would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, I will give this a shot, I think it should work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just caching your data in memory will limit your ability to scale-out (one benefit of running it in Azure is that can be done easily).  To do what you want and not prevent scale-out, you might look at using a distributed caching layer.  This may help you understand this:

http://blogs.alachisoft.com/ncache/using-distributed-cache-in-entity-framework-applications/

However, if you do this, you have added a lot of complexity to your application.  I would first ask if you actually have a problem with the on-prem database?  Have you tested and proved that it doesn't perform?  I wouldn't try to solve this problem until it is really a problem.

App Service Hybrid Connections (that use service bus relays) are easy to setup and use and offer secure connections to on-prem data:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections

Comment: It's not that the DB can't perform, it's that security won't allow remote connections to it, or allow it to be hosted in Azure, thus tying my hands

Comment: You said "I don't want every query going through the service bus relay".  Why not?  I assumed performance, but is it something else?

Comment: Performance is the main reason, but also it would be a ton of overhead for the project that we don't really have the time or resources to accomplish.

Comment: When you say "service bus relay", you mean a hybrid connection, right?  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) - these are extremely easy to setup and use.  Any custom management of in-memory caching would be far more complex and error prone.

Comment: Yes that's correct, a hybrid connection for the db connection is what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to secure and open connectivity between On-Prem and Azure. The simple approach us using a VPN tunnel so that it secures the traffic. Other ways involve Express Routes which are not cheap. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/

However, if this is more of a software architecture question, then you are certainly limited to caching the data in Azure and periodically refreshing the cache/storage to limit the round trips between Azure and On-Prem.

Comment: "However, if this is more of a software architecture question, then you are certainly limited to caching the data in Azure and periodically refreshing the cache/storage to limit the round trips between Azure and On-Prem." Yes, that's what I want to do. Any idea how lol?

Comment: My question is why? Are you migrating from on prem to azure?